# Delayed Job not saving record sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a recurring delayed job that sends out a confirmation email and marks the order as completed so that the next time the delayed job runs the order will not be re-processed.

Sometimes (seems to be when a certain string is tied to a promo code field but that might just be a coincidence) the job processes and sends the email but does not save the record and mark it as completed. I have used IRB to set the record to what the code would and verified that the record is valid.

Any ideas why this might be happening or has anyone seen this happen?

```
class PaymentEmailAndLock < Struct.new(:blank)
    include Delayed::RecurringJob
    run_at '8:00pm'
    run_every 1.day
    timezone 'US/Eastern'
    queue 'dailyjobs'
    def perform
        time_set = 30.hours.ago..2.hours.ago
        @mail_and_lock = Cart.where(updated_at:time_set,payment_sent:true,complete_order_lock:false)
        @mail_and_lock.each do |obj|
            obj.complete_order_lock = true
            obj.survey_available = true
            obj.save
            if obj.payment == 1
                MessageMailer.delay(queue: 'mailers').message_payment_paper(obj.cust_email,obj)
            else
                MessageMailer.delay(queue: 'mailers').message_payment_digital(obj.cust_email,obj)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: There are no errors. The record is valid. Two records can be processed by this method and one will update and the other will just send the email.

Comment: Restarting one of my workers fixed this issue. I think the worker was running some older code instance and had not been reset in a while. Silly goof, but was aggravating none the less. @muistooshort please submit this as an answer and I will give you credit.